# where's the relevant rule for phase two name lookup of template instantiation in the current standard

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

```cpp
template<typename T>
void fun(T t){
   foo(t);  //#1 foo is a dependent name
}
void foo(int){
}
int main(){
  fun(0);  // #2 ill-formed
}
```

Since the unqualified-id `foo` is a dependent name as per [temp.dep#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.dep#2), So, the lookup name rule for this name should obey the following rule, which is mentioned in the note of [temp.dep#2]

> [ Note: Such names are unbound and are looked up at the point of the template instantiation ([temp.point]) in both the context of the template definition and the context of the point of instantiation ([temp.dep.candidate]). — end note ]

The lookup rule for a dependent name is clearly written in c++17 standard, that is:
[temp.dep.res#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.res#1)

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> > - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> > - Declarations from **namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context ([temp.point]) and from the definition context**.

And [temp.dep.candidate#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep.candidate#1)

> For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]) except that:
>
> > - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup, only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> > - For the part of the lookup **using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found**.

In other words, these rules mean that only ADL is used to perform in phase two lookup.

However, I cannot find the relevant rule in the current standard(i.e, c++20). [temp.dep.res#1] has been removed from the current standard. [temp.dep.candidate#1] has been modified as:
[temp.dep.candidate#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.dep.candidate#1)

> For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules from the template definition context ([basic.lookup.unqual], [basic.lookup.argdep]). [ Note: **For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces ([basic.lookup.argdep]), function declarations found in the template instantiation context are found by this lookup, as described in [basic.lookup.argdep]**. — end note ] If the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation contexts, then the program has undefined behavior.

It's just to be a note in the current standard. It appears to me that the current standard does not clearly describe how the lookup rule performs for an unqualified dependent name in a function call. In the current standard, where's the relevant rule states that only **ADL** will perform in the second phase? It's unclear. If the usual unqualified look rule will be performed in the second phase, **#2** would be well-formed due to `void foo(int)` can be found in the instantiation context by unqualified lookup. If I miss anything, where's the relevant rule?

Comment: I have deja vu from this question

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The example appears in many questions on SO. Most questions ask why `fun(0);` is ill-formed. This question is asked how the lookup rule performs on a dependent name and the relevant rule in the current standard. If I correctly understand the answer of NicolBolas, it seems that the unqualified lookup and ADL both perform in the instantiation context.

Comment: The term “two-phase” is more confusing than useful—the two phases are sometimes taken as lookup for non-dependent and dependent names, but it’s easy to take the note to mean that the phases are “definition context” and “point of instantiation” and the normative text to mean that they are “unqualified lookup” and (its subset?) “ADL”.  This leaves ADL from the definition context ambiguously categorized, and with modules some declarations are found only by that kind of lookup.

Comment: @DavisHerring  I find that the wording "the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules from the template definition context" has been removed from P1787. The lookup rule for the dependent name is replaced by[temp.res#general-1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-1)("If the name is dependent (as specified in [temp.dep]), it is looked up for each specialization (after substitution) because the lookup depends on a template parameter."). Does it imply that these declarations found by unqualified name lookup from **instantiation context** can be as the candidates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words, these rules mean that only ADL is used to perform in phase two lookup.

This is the wrong conclusion to draw from the given specification quotes. You seem to be confusing two different concepts.

The first concept is what is commonly called "two-phase lookup": the fact that when a template gets parsed, names which are dependent on template parameters cannot be looked up at parse time. They can only be lookup up at instantiation time. There are two phases of lookup: one for non-dependent names, and one for dependent names.

The second concept is just name lookup, which has two scopes of names to search: regular unqualified lookup (defined in [basic.lookup.unqual]) and argument-dependent lookup (defined in [basic.lookup.argdep]). Unqualified lookup searches in the scope of the code itself, while ADL searches in the scope of the namespace of a function's arguments.

Both phases of template name lookup use *both* of these scopes. To be clear, dependent name lookup *also* does unqualified lookup. This is why one of the bullet points you quoted said "for the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup... ". If dependent name lookup didn't use the rules for unqualified name lookup, it wouldn't have mentioned them.

Now, dependent name lookup does restrict what the candidate names are compared to the regular rules. But it doesn't restrict it to *just* ADL; it does both scopes of lookup.

These restrictions used to be specified in [temp.dep.candidate]/1, as you pointed out. But they got moved around a bit.

For the unqualified lookup part, the new [temp.dep.candidate]/1 covers that as you quoted it, because it says "usual lookup rules **from the template definition context**". This specifies the context of the unqualified lookup as being the template's definition only.

Note that the second bullet point also says to look in that scope, so it covers part of that.

The rest of the second bullet point is covered by [[basic.lookup.argdep]/4.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lookup.argdep#4.5):

> If the lookup is for a dependent name ([temp.dep], [temp.dep.candidate]), any declaration D in N is visible if D would be visible to qualified name lookup ([namespace.qual]) at any point in the instantiation context ([module.context]) of the lookup, unless D is declared in another translation unit, attached to the global module, and is either discarded ([module.global.frag]) or has internal linkage.

This expands the lookup to include the "instantiation context", which largely matches the C++17 text (though with module-based modifications).

Comment: Do you mean the usual name lookup will be performed in instantiation time from the instantiation context again? which will also undergo the usual unqualified name lookup followed by ADL, merely the rule restricts these candidates that be found by usual unqualified name lookup from the **instatiation context** do not add to the candidate set(i.e, only consider these candidates found by ADL), Right?

Comment: @jackX: "*only consider these candidates found by ADL*" No. Unqualified name lookup still happens during dependent name lookup, but it does not find names based on the "instantiation context". It still looks for them during the second phase, but it looks for names accessible from the "template definition context" only.

Comment: I try to reword my understanding. When a template is instantiated, the name lookup will perform for the dependent name, the difference is that these declarations found by unqualified name lookup are found from the **definition context** and these declarations found by ADL are found from both the **definition context** and **instantiation context**. This also implies that these declarations that can be found by unqualified name lookup from **instantiation context** are not candidates. Right?

Comment: @jackX: What you've said here is correct. But that doesn't really change anything about your question, since it's the same in both C++17 and C++20. And as I've indicated in my answer, they just moved things around a bit.

Comment: You indicated that the original second bullet in [temp.dep.candidate#1] was moved to [basic.lookup.argdep]/4.5. One more question, it appears to me that the wording **usual lookup rules** is non-normative, Does it include "ADL"?

Comment: @jackX: "*it appears to me that the wording usual lookup rules is non-normative*" The words "usual lookup rules" not only are *outside* of a `[note:]` block, but they are also followed by links to two sections. What they mean seems pretty clear and is very "normative".

Comment: Do you mean "usual lookup rules" include both "unqualified name lookup" and "argument dependent lookup"? If it is, how to interpret [basic.lookup.unqual#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lookup.unqual#3)(For purposes of determining (during parsing) whether an expression is a postfix-expression for a function call, the **usual name lookup rules apply**.), it implies that `ADL` is not categorized to **usual lookup rules**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229025/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-jack-x).